# To pass integer value in render partial form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a task to pass one integer value to another partial form. My code was this

```
<div class="fields">
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content, "Student" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br />
  </p>
  <h4>Address</h4>
  <% i = 1 %>
  <% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'answer_fields', :locals => {:i => i, :f => builder} %>
    <% i = i + 1 %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Address", f, :answers %></p>
</div>
```

But in the partial form i got an error like

```
undefined local variable or method `i'
```

My partial form is

```
<p class="fields">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.label :content, "Address"+i.to_s %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :content %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
```

How can i pass the value of i to other partial form?

Comment: drop the i initialization line below by 1 more line and see.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct.

```
   Please try with this..

   <%= render :partial => 'answer_fields', :locals => {:i => i.to_i, :f => builder} %>
```

Comment: for 2.3.5 also same syntax. please put <% raise params.inspect %> in the top of the partial file. and check what are the params are coming?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the above code. I even tested this in my rails application in case I was missing something.

You don't have another template that is calling this partial without the :i local do you?